# Replacing numbers in a string with a modified number using regex - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, replace

I'm new to javascript so apologies if I've missed something simple. I'm working on a script to take a string from one cell in Sheets, add VAT at 5% to any applicable numbers and output the amended string in a new cell. I'm happy with the regex capturing the numbers I need, but getting the amended string correct is proving tricky.

So far the script looks like this:

```
function strReplace() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   var str = sheet.getRange(4,2).getValue(); // A cell with a string like this: "ID: 10101010101010 | Price 1: £4.54 | Price 2: £2.87"

   var regex = /\d{1,8}(?:\.\d{1,8})/g  // Regex to ignore numbers greater than 8 digits, including decimals

   var newStr = str.match(regex);


   for (var x = 0; x < newStr.length; x++) {

    var newRates = newStr[x]*1.05;
    var output = str.replace(newStr, newRates)

    sheet.getRange(4,3).setValue(output);

    }                   
  }
```

I've tried a bunch of variations but with no success. I feel there is an easier way to achieve what I'm looking for from what I already have. Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to include an example of the output that the code produces, as well as an example of the output that you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this kind of thing, you use the function callback version of `replace`:

```js
var str = "ID: 10101010101010 | Price 1: £4.54 | Price 2: £2.87";
var regex = /\d{1,8}(?:\.\d{1,8})/g;  // Regex to ignore numbers greater than 8 digits, including decimals
var output = str.replace(regex, function(match) {
    return 1.05 * match;
});
console.log(output);
```

You might choose to use `parseFloat(match)` rather than just using `match`, which relies on `*` coercing the string to number.

And you might consider `.toFixed(2)` on the result to round and format to two places (depending on whether you want to round the way it rounds). For instance:

```js
var str = "ID: 10101010101010 | Price 1: £4.54 | Price 2: £2.87";
var regex = /\d{1,8}(?:\.\d{1,8})/g;  // Regex to ignore numbers greater than 8 digits, including decimals
var output = str.replace(regex, function(match) {
    return (1.05 * match).toFixed(2);
});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

basically your solution is very close, you just needed tot assign the `str.replace`, use the `newStr[x]` and also wait to end the `for` to assign it into the cell.

check the sample below.

```js
function strReplace() {

  let str = "ID: 10101010101010 | Price 1: £4.54 | Price 2: £2.87";
  var regex = /\d{1,8}(?:\.\d{1,8})/g

  var newStr = str.match(regex);

  for (var x = 0; x < newStr.length; x++) {
    var newRates = parseFloat(newStr[x]) * 1.05;
    str = str.replace(newStr[x], newRates)
  }

  return str;
}

var replaced = strReplace();

console.log(replaced)
```